# Increment count with click of button while decrementing another count and vice versa without reseting to default score

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three .js files here. This code works fine except the count scores don't correlate with the other clicking of the button. I would like to add these requirements to my code as well: Each service will store the counter that displays above/below the buttons as a property on the service. Each service will have at least 3 methods: increment, decrement, and reset, which resets the counter to 100.
The counter property in the services must NOT be directly manipulated by a controller - you should create public methods in your services to perform the operations instead, which are called by the controller.

```
//home.js
var app = angular.module('MyApp');

app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'RedService', 'BlueService', function ($scope, $rs, $bs) {
$scope.title = "The Mighty Clicker";

$scope.redOutput = 100;
$scope.blueOutput = 100;

$scope.countRed = function () {
    $rs.countUp++;
    $scope.redOutput = $rs.countUp;
    $bs.coundDown--;
    $scope.blueOutput = $bs.coundDown;
}

$scope.countBlue = function () {
    $bs.countUp++;
    $scope.blueOutput = $bs.countUp;
    $rs.countDown--;
    $scope.redOutput = $rs.countDown;
}

}]);


//blueService.js
var app = angular.module("MyBlueService", []);

app.service("BlueService", function () {
    this.countUp = 100;
    this.coundDown = 100;
})

//redService.js
var app = angular.module("MyRedService", []);

app.service("RedService", function() {
    this.countUp = 100;
    this.countDown = 100;
})
```

---

here is my HTML code
    //html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 buttons">
       <h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1>
        <button class="btn red" ng-click="countRed()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{redOutput}}</h1>

         <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <button class="btn blue" ng-click="countBlue()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{blueOutput}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpzvI.png)

Comment: pretty unclear what you are asking

Comment: Please include your HTML.  A plunker or fiddle would help users to understand what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to click a button which increments a score and decrements another score. Vice versa with the other button I have. However, when I click the other button, it doesn't continue where the scores are but starts from the default score 100

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the rules are but from what I understand I made a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/lrMgM8lcm0FtCIQbZLlf?p=preview

It looks like the code works without needing change except for the typos :D

```
$scope.blueOutput = blueService.countDown;
```

You mispelled countDown with coundDown

Comment: thanks for the link! So i notice when I click on the first blue button the score increments and the red score decrements. however, when I click one the red button, both scores default to 100 and count up and down from there. Is there a way where both buttons will correlate with the same score. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You need to have two buttons, if click first -> it counter gets up and counter second one gets down. I have done it by starting from Your code,  but I've simplified the solution, so both services has only one counter and I set services directly into scope to avoid many assignments and variables. Check my working example:

```js
//home.js
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'RedService', 'BlueService', function ($scope, $rs, $bs) {
$scope.title = "The Mighty Clicker";

//services to scope directly
$scope.$rs=$rs;
$scope.$bs=$bs;

$scope.countRed = function () {
    $rs.count++;
    $bs.count--;
}

$scope.countBlue = function () {
    $bs.count++;
    $rs.count--;
}

}]);


//blueService.js

app.service("BlueService", function () {
    this.count = 100;//single counter
})

//redService.js

app.service("RedService", function() {
    this.count = 100; //single counter
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeController" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 buttons">
       <h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1>
        <button class="btn red" ng-click="countRed()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{$rs.count}}</h1>

        <button class="btn blue" ng-click="countBlue()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{$bs.count}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT. AFTER COMMENT.**

```js
//home.js
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', 'RedService', 'BlueService', function ($scope, $rs, $bs) {
$scope.title = "The Mighty Clicker";

//services to scope directly
$scope.$rs=$rs;
$scope.$bs=$bs;

$scope.countRed = function () {
  
    $rs.increment();
    $bs.decrement();
}

$scope.countBlue = function () {
    $bs.increment();
    $rs.decrement();
}

$scope.reset=function(){

  $bs.reset();
  $rs.reset();
  
}

}]);


//return constructor
//create for DRY
app.service("Counter",function(){

    return function(){
    this.count = 100;//single counter
  
    this.increment=function(){
       
        this.count++;
    };
  
    this.decrement=function(){
       
        this.count--;
    };
  
    this.reset=function(){
    
        this.count=100;
    };

    };
     
});

//blueService.js

app.service("BlueService", ["Counter",function ($cf) {
    
   return new $cf;
  
}]);

//redService.js

app.service("RedService", ["Counter",function ($cf) {
    
   return new $cf;
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="HomeController" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 buttons">
       <h1 class='title'>{{title}}</h1>
        <button class="btn red" ng-click="countRed()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{$rs.count}}</h1>

        <button class="btn blue" ng-click="countBlue()">Button</button>
        <h1>{{$bs.count}}</h1>
      
        <button ng-click="reset()">Reset counters</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! This is exactly what I was wanting! Now, do you think you can add these requirements to the above code: Each service will store the counter that displays above/below the buttons as a property on the service. Each service will have at least 3 methods: increment, decrement, and reset, which resets the counter to 100.
The counter property in the services must NOT be directly manipulated by a controller - you should create public methods in your services to perform the operations instead, which are called by the controller.

Comment: @SaiaFonua this is your code, I only changed few things. Look at changes and implement it.

Comment: I can do something like that wait a moment.

Comment: i tried but my controller was not picking up the method I wrote in my service.

Comment: @MaciejSikora anything yet? Or did you want to see my code first. This is just an assignment in my bootcamp.. it's not like I'm getting graded on it.. they just want me to learn it

Comment: @SaiaFonua i think it is what You need. Check second code.

Comment: @MaciejSikora beautiful! Thanks a whole heap !

Comment: @SaiaFonua no problem, if answer i correct, check it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @gyc mentioned in his post, there was a typo. I have created the plunkr with the same design architecture (3 modules and each of them with a service).

RedApp and BlueApp modules are added to MainApp module as dependencies and used their in myApp's controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module("MainApp", ["RedApp", "BlueApp"]);

myApp.controller("MyAppController", ["$scope", "RedAppService", "BlueAppService", function($scope, $rs, $bs) {

  $scope.title = "The Mighty Clicker";

  $scope.redOutput = 100;
  $scope.blueOutput = 100;

  $scope.countRed = function() {
    $rs.countUp++;
    $scope.redOutput = $rs.countUp;
    $bs.countDown--;
    $scope.blueOutput = $bs.countDown;
  }

  $scope.countBlue = function() {
    $bs.countUp++;
    $scope.blueOutput = $bs.countUp;
    $rs.countDown--;
    $scope.redOutput = $rs.countDown;
  }


}]);

var redApp = angular.module("RedApp", []);

var blueApp = angular.module("BlueApp", []);

redApp.service("RedAppService", function() {

  this.countUp = 100;
  this.countDown = 100;
});

blueApp.service("BlueAppService", function() {

  this.countUp = 100;
  this.countDown = 100;
});
```